# Facebook thinks I am blocked from a group chat

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I'm having an issue with my Facebook account. A few days ago, my friend was messing round and kicked me from the group chat that we and my other friends have. He's since added me back but I still can't seem to message in the chat since it still thinks I'm kicked when on their phones, it tells them I'm actually in the chat.

I do get notifications coming through when they send something but I can only see the message for a split second then it goes away.

I have tried logging in/out, deleting messenger on my phone, deactivating my Facebook account, deleting the chat and adding it to archive then reopening it but nothing seems to be working.

Is there a way I can reset my Facebook account so it stops bugging out. I don't really want to have to create a whole new chat just for me as there's quite a few people in it and we've had it for so long.

I have contacted support but have yet to hear anything on the matter. Anyone else had this issue?

Answer (score -1):

Well buddy do one thing 
Try to remove yourself from the chat and then tell your friend to add you again
if it does not helps so then ask help from Facebook directly